# Overlap plots in pls package

Tags: r, plot, overlap, points

I am using **pls** package in R. I am trying to plot cross validated predictions for my dataset which is equivalent to `gasoline` data set provided in the package.

```
plot(gas1, ncomp = 2, asp = 1, newdata= train, line=TRUE, col='blue')
```

I would like to plot on the same plot to compare how training data and test data predictions compare.

```
plot(gas1, ncomp = 2, asp=1, newdata=test, line =TRUE)
```

I cannot figure how to plot the two in one plot window. I tried the first plot command above followed by:

```
points(gas1, ncomp=2, newdata=test)
```

but this needs x and y inputs. I do not understand **pls** well enough to know how to get the x and predicted y out. Can someone please help?

Comment: What are gas1 and train?

Comment: gas1 is the output from the pls command and train is the training data and test is the test data which are derived from the original gaoline data by splitting them into two parts. The code for the pls is gas1 =plsr(octane ~ NIR, ncomp = 10, data = train, validation = "LOO")

Comment: @gujax Please provide with a reproducible example. How can we load train?

Answer (score 0):

> pls:::plot.mvr

is hidden in package pls and shows you the code that is used when you call *plot(gas1)*. It is calling the following functions, which you can study to understand how to manipulate the mvr object:

- pls:::predplot.mvr
- validationplot
- coefplot
- scoreplot
- loadingplot
- pls:::biplot.mvr
- corrplot

you can override the function plot.mvr or any of the subfunction to change the behavior (for instance add an argument to plot on the same graph.

Comment: Thank you RockScience. I am still trying to understand plot.mvr and its internal routines. Looks like I have to understand how to get the prediction y values and then I can use the R's generic plot command. Unfortunately, not yet clear on how to get predicted y values for ncomponents. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Ok,
I figured out this so far and works. 

    data1<-drop(predict(gas1, ncomp = 2, newdata = train))
    plot(gas1, ncomp = 2, asp = 1, newdata=test, line = TRUE)
    points(ytrain,data1,col='blue')

This works fortunately because the abline for train and test data are the same.
But I was wondering what If I had to superimpose plots for two different training coefficients?

In that case how do I get the abline for data plotted by 'points'?

Comment: @gujax sorry but I can't help you further if you don't tell us where train comes from

Comment: The data file gasoline is split into train and test data set. One can do a random split. I just split it half and half.